# How to create a Nested Menu using Dynamic Data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a nested menu using Dynamic Data. The first layer is working correctly. But I have a problem in showing the sub-menus, when I click on the parent the sub-menu replaced the main menu. Here is my code:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.getCatalogueCategories(1, { pos: '6196319a431f76d2acd3c27d' }).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.catalogueCategoriesL1 = res;
      this.catalogueCategories = res;
    });
  }
  getSubCatalogueCategories(layer: number, parent: string, index: number) {
    this.appService.getCatalogueCategories(layer, { pos: '6196319a431f76d2acd3c27d' }, parent).subscribe((subCategories) => {
      (this.catalogueCategories[index] as any).children = subCategories;
      // show subMenu
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <button
    mat-button
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="categories"
     >
       <span class="pl-1 text-gray-90">All Departments</span>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #categories="matMenu" yposition="below">
      <div *ngFor="let cat1 of catalogueCategories">
        <button (click)="getSubCatalogueCategories(cat1.layer+1,cat1.id,index)" mat-menu-item>
{{cat1.name}}</button>
     </div>
 </mat-menu>
```

Comment: I feel that you should remove the ng-template, just: `<mat-menu #categories="matMenu"><ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categories"><button..></ng-container></mat-menu>`

Comment: It works but now the submenu has replaced the main menu. The list is not expanded. Do you have any idea how to expand the menu ?

Comment: Not use "div" else "ng-container" to not create additional tags (you can also put the *ngFor inside the "button". NOTE: When you use a template reference variable if is inside another *ngFor -to show the buttons of the fisrt layer- you have no problem: Angular know at what menu are you indicate. Sorry, it's impossible help without know the way of your data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both function calls return an Observable of an Array you could do something like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getMainMenuItems()
    .pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log(res)),
      mergeAll(),
      switchMap(res => {
        return this.getSubMenuItems(res.id).pipe(
          map(subsRes => ({mainID: res.id, mainLabel: res.label, SubMenus: subsRes})),
        );
       }),
       toArray()
    )
    .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
}

getMainMenuItems(): Observable<any[]> {
  return of([
    { id: 1, label: 'one' },
    { id: 2, label: 'two' },
    { id: 3, label: 'three' },
  ]);
}

getSubMenuItems(idParm: number): Observable<any[]> {
  return of([
    { id: idParm, label: 'WhoKnows' },
    { id: idParm + 1, label: 'WhoKnows+1' },
  ]);
}
```

This construct will:

1. first make an observable for every item in the main menu array.
2. For every main menu item switchMap will call the submenu function to get those details and in the map function this is combined to a new object.
3. toArray() will make an array out of that so you can assign it to you local variable.